# Merging 2 files without a common key

Tags: r, merge, spss

I have 2 files. One is a `time_file` which has 3000 rows and the other is `userid` file which has 2000 rows. I want to merge the two, so that each row (ID) in the `userid` file is paired with the full data from each row of the `time_file`.

Rows 1-3000 would show the first `userid` with each of the dates.

Rows 3001-6000 would show the 2nd `userid` with each of the dates, and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Time file

```
    mo  day year    date
    11  1   2015    11/1/2015
    11  2   2015    11/2/2015
    11  3   2015    11/3/2015
    11  4   2015    11/4/2015
    11  5   2015    11/5/2015
    .
    .
```

userid file

```
userid
154
155
157
158
159
160
.
.
```

Ideal format(what I want)

```
    mo  day year    date        userid
    11  1   2015    11/1/2015   154
    11  2   2015    11/2/2015   154
    11  3   2015    11/3/2015   154
    11  4   2015    11/4/2015   154
    11  5   2015    11/5/2015   154
    .
    .
    3   28  2017    3/28/2017   154
    3   29  2017    3/29/2017   154
    3   30  2017    3/30/2017   154
    3   31  2017    3/31/2017   154
    11  1   2015    11/1/2015   155
    11  2   2015    11/2/2015   155
    11  3   2015    11/3/2015   155
    11  4   2015    11/4/2015   155
    11  5   2015    11/5/2015   155
    11  6   2015    11/6/2015   155
```

Comment: Please share sample of your data using `dput()` (not `str` or `head` or picture/screenshot) so others can help. 
See more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1

Comment: @Tung : I've attached the screenshot! but will try to using dput() or another way to share the data sample.

Comment: The SPSS solution is through `STATS CARTPROD` command. will post some code if the question is reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution in R I can think of, assuming you've gotten your time data in a data frame and your user data in a vector:

```
final_df <- cbind(date_df, "userid" = rep(user, each = 3000))
```

This will repeat each user_id 3000 times, then bind the user_id column to the date data frame.

Answer (score 0):

In SPSS you can use the cartesian product function for this:

First this recreates your example data:

```
data list free/mo  day year (3f4)   date (a12).
begin data.
11  1   2015    11/1/2015
11  2   2015    11/2/2015
11  3   2015    11/3/2015
11  4   2015    11/4/2015
11  5   2015    11/5/2015
end data.
DATASET NAME time_file.

data list free/ userid.
begin data.
154,155,157,158,159,160
end data.
DATASET NAME userid.
```

This will now combine the two tables like you requested:

```
STATS CARTPROD VAR1=userid INPUT2=time_file VAR2=mo  day year date 
/SAVE OUTFILE="path\your combined data.sav".
```